# Smaller free remote control telescopes?

Tags: astronomy, telescopes

There are several online services that let you control a large 
telescope (eg, lightbuckets.com and slooh.com), even some that are 
free (eg, telescope.org).

Unfortunately, the pay services are expensive, and you get very little 
reserved time on the scopes. The free services are painfully slow: I 
had to wait several months for a picture of Jupiter I wanted.

Has anyone set up automated (ideally free) remote access to a smaller 
telescope? I'd much rather play with a 10" telescope in real-time than 
a larger one in limited/delayed time.

In fact, even a CCD or camera would be nice for wide-angle shots.

Comment: I had a brief relationship with a project called Remote Access Astronomy Project at UCSB in the early 1990. Alas, [it seems to have died in 1999](http://www.deepspace.ucsb.edu/pastproj.html).

Answer (score 4):

I doubt you'll find such a service. Setting up a remote control telescope is technically complex, and hence expensive. Most of the people I know with smaller remote controlled telescopes have invested a lot of time and money into them, and are unlikely to want to share them for free.

Answer (score 1):

In any case, this would be an awesome tinkering project for an amateur observatory. I know an astronomy club whose 1m telescope is unused most of the time.

Maybe you can find an amateur observatory in your region and use their telescope. Maybe you even get them to build such a cool internet service.